# build tensorflow r1.12 mkl on Windows using bazel, result in link error

Tags: windows, tensorflow, build, bazel, intel-mkl

I'm trying to compile tensorflow with MKL support on Windows 10 64bit via Bazel with command:

```
bazel build --config=mkl --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

on the following environments:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- Tensorflow 1.12
- Bazel 0.18

I have no idea what's wrong with my config, I have tried tensorflow r1.11 and r1.12. both ending up with same problem, the log is:

```
    ERROR: F:/tools/tf1.12/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:3766:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so' failed (Exit 1000): link.exe failed: error executing command
  cd C:/users/10267/_bazel_10267/udaytyio/execroot/org_tensorflow
  SET LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;
    SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\;;C:\WINDOWS\system32
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe
    SET PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Program Files/Python36/lib/site-packages
    SET TEMP=C:\Users\10267\AppData\Local\Temp
    SET TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0
    SET TF_NEED_CUDA=0
    SET TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0
    SET TMP=C:\Users\10267\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/amd64/link.exe /nologo /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE -defaultlib:advapi32.lib -DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib /MACHINE:X64 @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so-2.params /OPT:ICF /OPT:REF /DEF:bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_filtered_def_file.def /ignore:4070
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/lpthread'; ignored

bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/nsync/nsync_cpp.lib : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during CImplib::EmitThunk

  Version 14.00.24215.1

  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
  ExceptionAddress         = 00007FF7E0686896 (00007FF7E0670000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\link.exe"
  NumberParameters         = 00000002
  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 0000000000000000
  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 0000000000000008

CONTEXT:
  Rax    = 0000000000000000  R8     = 00007FF7E076FBE0
  Rbx    = 0000000000000000  R9     = 00007FF7E076E9F0
  Rcx    = 0000000000000000  R10    = 0000000000000000
  Rdx    = 00007FF7E076FBD8  R11    = 0000000000000000
  Rsp    = 000000082B71DE68  R12    = 00007FF7E073D950
  Rbp    = 000001A60F8F8360  E13    = 0000000000000000
  Rsi    = 0000000000008000  R14    = 0000000000000000
  Rdi    = 000001A6102AA300  R15    = 0000000000000000
  Rip    = 00007FF7E0686896  EFlags = 0000000000010246
  SegCs  = 0000000000000033  SegDs  = 000000000000002B
  SegSs  = 000000000000002B  SegEs  = 000000000000002B
  SegFs  = 0000000000000053  SegGs  = 000000000000002B
  Dr0    = 0000000000000000  Dr3    = 0000000000000000
  Dr1    = 0000000000000000  Dr6    = 0000000000000000
  Dr2    = 0000000000000000  Dr7    = 0000000000000000
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 3172.917s, Critical Path: 253.76s
INFO: 3875 processes: 3875 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

And I've also tried to build it without --config=mkl term, which is successful, so I wonder if the error has kinda relation with mkl ?

Answer (score 0):

please try the workaround described in this github issue response from Intel rep.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23420

or use conda and follow the instructions in the "Windows and MacOS" section here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide